# Mobile Ads webview registration Inappwebview plugin Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to port a website as mobile app using Flutter [inappwebview plugin](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/5.x.x/webview/in-app-webview).

This website is integrated with google Ads. So trying to integrate with [Mobile ads plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads)

so that google Ads best practices are met following this [google support docs](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/flutter/webview).

Mobile ads uses webview_flutter plugin but I really like this inappwebview plugin and I want to keep it as the web_view_flutter plugin is basic and does not support file upload and etc... inherently

Can you point me in the right direction how to utilize this ***InAppWebviewController*** to access the underlying webview and find its (identifier)key->Int because all the Mobile Ads plugin does here with ***registerWebView*** is the following ?

```
await instanceManager.channel.invokeMethod<void>(
                    'MobileAds#registerWebView',
                    <dynamic, dynamic>{
                      'webViewId': webViewKey,
                    },
                  );
```

As of now, am clueless how to find the **underlying webview (identifier)** key and invoke the ***MethodChannel*** instance's unimplemented methods using ***InappWebviewController*** object.

Or please suggest any other better ways to handle this ?

My App State block code goes like this.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  InAppWebViewGroupOptions groupOptions = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
          useHybridComposition: true, builtInZoomControls: false));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          if (widget.browser.isOpened()) {
            await widget.browser.close();
          }
          return Future.value(true);
        },
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: BlankBar(),
            body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return InAppWebView(
                key: webViewKey,
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://webview-api-for-ads-test.glitch.me/")),
                initialOptions: groupOptions,
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                  *//This line not works as MobileAds needs Webview_flutter's controller*
                  //MobileAds.instance.registerWebView(controller);
                  
                  *//Tried this workaround but not works.*
                  /*await instanceManager.channel.invokeMethod<void>(
                    'MobileAds#registerWebView',
                    <dynamic, dynamic>{
                      'webViewId': webViewKey,
                    },
                  );*/
                },
                onLoadStart: (controller, url) {},
                onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {},
                onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {},
                onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {},
                onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {},
                onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                  print(consoleMessage);
                },
              );
            })));
  }
}
```